# How to use ClassPathResource class in WSO2 Axis2 service?

Tags: apache-axis, wso2

I putted a text file in java class path on WSO2 Axis2 service project and uploaded it to WSO2 AS server , but my Axis2 service can not find it by ClassPathResource class. The Exception as the following:

> IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [xxx.xml]

I am sure my xxx.xml file has been uploaded in the .aar package on AS server:

> ```
> service.aar
> ...[META-INF]
> ...[package dir]
> ...xxx.xml
> ```

How to use ClassPathResource class to find a file resource under WSO2 Axis2 service??

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the "xxx.xml" file at the top level of the hierarchy of the service archive, you can use the following java snippet to access it within the Axis2 service classes.

........
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/xxx.xml");
.......

Hope this helps!

Cheers,
Prabath

Comment: or you can also use, "InputStream is = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/xxx.xml");" as well